# Android Maps marker OnClick for each loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

so I created a new marker each rotation however I am unsure how I would add an OnClick method and a listener for each marker, could someone show me how I would do this?

```
    Public static void addMapMarker(ArrayList<int> Results){
        if(Results.size() < 20)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != Results.size(); i++)
            {
                temp = Results.get(i).intValue();

                Log.d("Logger", "Adding marker");

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(StationsList.get(temp).getLon(), StationsList.get(temp).getLat()))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.dot))
                        .title(StationsList.get(temp).getName()));
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Unrelated - your code seems to have the LatLng constructor backwards - it should be latitude,longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, set `Listener` on Map itself. you will get `Marker` and its detail. You don't have to set listeners for each marker separately.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

              // do anything here when a marker lick

           }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zaid! :)

Comment: @glad to help. if it resolve your problem. kindly click on accepted answer.